# Constructing the formula for randomForest classification and then using predict

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
RFmodel = randomForest(as.factor(trainset[,55]) ~ . , trainset, ntree = ntree.array[i], mtry = mtry.array[j], maxnodes = maxnodes.array[k])
RFyhat = predict(RFmodel , testset[,-55])
RFyhat = as.numeric(levels(RFyhat)[RFyhat])
Testerr.randomforest[i,j,k] = sum(RFyhat != testset[,55])/length(testset[,55])
```

This code throws an error in the second line, namely, it says:

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'V55' not found

However, strangely enough, the error disappears when I do one of two things, 1) change trainset[,55] in the first line to trainset$V55, 2) change testset[,-55] to testset.  However, the error rates are slightly different (I imagine because in the latter, I'm using testset[,55] as an independent variable, but that's just me guessing).  Could anyone explain to me what the difference between using trainset[,55] and trainset$V55 is, and what the proper usage in this scenario would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're misusing R's formula interface. The formula:

```
as.factor(trainset[,55]) ~ .
```

evaluated within the data set `trainset` will include the left hand side as the response and *all the variables in trainset* as predictors. That's because you haven't given a name of a variable in the left hand side, so the `.` is interpretted as everything "else", but everything "else" in this case is everything, since R can't find something called "as.factor(trainset[,55])" in `trainset`.

You probably wanted to do something more like:

```
trainset$V55 <- as.factor(trainset$V55)
RFmodel = randomForest(V55 ~ . , trainset, ...)
```

One consequence of this mistake is that you're including `V55` both as the response and as a predictor. I'm surprised that you aren't simply getting a 0% error rate, which is what happens when you do something equivalent in this example:

```
rf <- randomForest(as.factor(iris[,5]) ~ ., data=iris)
```

which uses `Species` as a response, but also includes it as a predictor. You can verify that by looking at either the `$call` or `$terms` attribute of the resulting random forest object.

Comment: Thank you! That helped immensely.  A couple small follow-ups: Since this is a classification problem, I need a factor in the formula, hence as.factor(trainset[,55]).  Would as.factor(trainset$V55) in the formula work as desired, or do I need to actually convert it to a factor and then run the model?  Second, when I utilize the predict() function, do I need to restrict the dataset I input to precisely the columns I require, or will it only predict using the independent variables defined in the model formula?  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Justin (a) `as.factor(trainset$V55)` should be sufficient. (b) you just need to make sure that everything used in the model (as a predictor) is in the test set; extra variables should be ignored.